# Is there any function can keep tracking current visible region in Mapkit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Here is what I have done for my app, as you can see, on the top is the `mapView`, down there is the `TableView`. What I want to achieve is that when I zoom in (move to, or zoom out) into certain region in the `mapView`, the `tableView` down there can present corresponding user information. 
In order to achieve that feature, here is my solution:

1. I made several invisible coordinations on the map, those coordinations are the regions which contain the user information.
2. I want to use `mapView.visibleMapRect` to get the current visible region, then I want to use `MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapRect, invisibleCoordination)` to check if the current visible region contain certain invisible coordination, if `MKMapRectContainsPoint` returns true, then I will make the web service request, then present it on the `TableView`.

However, I don't know where to put these functions, if I want to solve this problem, I have to keep tracking the mapView.visibleMapRect and `MKMapRectContainsPoint`. I tried `locationManager(:didUpdateLocations)`, but this function is not keep calling during the `mapView` is presented.

I am not sure my solution is a good one, if you can tell me a better solution, I am looking forward to seeing it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in the MKMapViewDelegate which called every time when the region is changed. I think this is the one you are looking for.

The method you tried before, didUpdateLocations, is invoked when the location of the device is changed.

MKMapViewDelegate

Swift:

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

So in your case

Swift:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
    {
        // Do what you want to do here!
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController < MKMapViewDelegate >

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Do what you want to do here
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you have a better idea how to implement this feature?

Comment: If you want to do is what you wrote above I think you are on the right track!! :)